# How to Copy a user profile in Active Directoty

Tags: active-directory

Hi I have a user with LOTS of access groups that will take me a very long time to copy across manually.

Is there a simple way to copy a users profile (or duplicate it) on AD?

I have checked and I can't see any "copy" etc any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to copy the user's profile (ie: C:\Users\<user>) or you talking about their security group membership?

Comment: their AD profile and access rights etc not their local profile

Comment: AD profile as in their AD user object? Are you copying your user from one AD to another AD? If you want to copy their security group membership, you can use Powershell to get user's group membership info (`get-aduser <username> -properties memberOf`).

Comment: Hi Sorry It's not liking the get-aduser any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid adding the new user to a member of all the necessary groups, it's very simple to copy the AD object:

[image]

Simply right click, and select Copy...

Comment: As I said we can't see a "copy" this may be a privilege issue due to the size of the company or outdated software.

Comment: Ahhh, that's no good... Do you know if you can use PowerShell?

Comment: IMO, if "Copy" isn't there, then you should worry about getting yourself the right permissions first.

Comment: @DavidGolding - You need to determine if its a permsission issue or not.  If its caused by a version issue we need to know that information.

Comment: we do have powershell and we will try the comment above later, however We can't upgrade etc due to it being implemented on an international scale and permissions wise this is what we do for a living so we "should" have access. I know this is little information but (1) I'm posting on behalf of a colleague and (2) We have both just left work as our shift is completed. Please feel free to think of other ways for this to work.

Comment: Thank you for all your help and I will let you people know how it goes in the morning :)

Comment: The user I was writing on behalf of just needed to take a step back from the stage they were at, both of us missed this, thank you for help regardless :)